Issue with H3: Uber’s Hexagonal Hierarchical Spatial Index
Currently, I am using the Uber H3 index library for my geospatial analysis. The version of the library is h3-3.7.7. If the version changes tomorrow, the corresponding H3 index for the given latitude and longitude might also change, affecting my entire dataset. How can I solve this issue?

I don't think it will ever change. They do change the library and API occasionally, but the index itself can be considered frozen.
I would check the release notes when switching the major releases, like 4.0.0, just in case, but as you can see "The grid itself ... is not changed in 4.0.0.".
https://h3geo.org/docs/library/migrating-3.x/
Minor releases are supposed to be non-breaking even for API, following Semantic versioning guidelines.
